# Is summoner monk on the banlist?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I was looking my self didn't see it but I could have missed the [Summoner Monk](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Summoner_Monk).

Answer (score 1):

A quick search on the [Current Official Banlist](http://www.yugioh-card.com/en/limited/) we can see that he is not on the list at all.

This means that it is *Unrestricted*, and you can use up to 3 copies of it in your deck builds.

**However**, also according to that Official page, seems that next Ban List is soon to come (this month), so there could be a chance the status of Summoner Monk changes.

---

On another note, I have always liked [Summoner Monk](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Summoner_Monk), and the fact that it is at 3 copies may strengthen some strategies out there. It is particularly useful to decks that have a high Spell Card ratio on their builds or that focus on Lvl 4 Xyz summoning (Harpies, Spellbook, Rescue Rabbit, Noble Knight, Gladiator Beast, and many, many others.).

In the case of my Harpies, this is a **great** addition to the deck, as it enables you to pull any Harpie (specially [Harpie Channeler](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Harpie_Channeler)) from the deck. The best possible scenario is to pull a Summoner Monk and activate its effect by discarding [Hysteric Sign](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Hysteric_Sign).

This means you get to summon a Harpie from the deck (opens many plays with Channeler) and at the end of the turn you get to search for up to 3 Harpie cards by effect of the Sign, refilling your hand for further combos next turn.

Comment: The last bit shouldn't be present without good reason imho. That mainly focuses on your opinion.

Comment: @VortexYT you can ignore it if you like, that is why I divided my answer into two, with the first part being the main and "objective" one. Although the second part contains my opinion it also illustrates the playability of this card, and some possible plays with it.